# Is there a benefit of calling a PHP file within an AJAX request, as supposed to a direct endpoint?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm writing an app which interacts with the Spotify Web API via AJAX requests.

I can do this in two ways.
I can use a direct (HTTPS?) GET or POST request to the Spotify endpoint as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url: `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=track:hysteria&type=track`,
    method: "GET",
    async: true,
    success: function(successData){
        console.log(successData);
    }
});
```

Or I could call a .php file using a php wrapper to communicate to Spotify:

```
query="hysteria";
$.ajax({
    url: 'getSong.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {data:query},
    async: true,
    success: function(successData) {
        console.log(JSON.Parse(successData))
    }
})
```

**getSong.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require '../vendor/autoload.php';

    //Create new spotify session and take accesstoken from session.
    $api = new SpotifyWebAPI\SpotifyWebAPI();
    $accessToken = $_SESSION["accessToken"];
    $api->setAccessToken($accessToken);

    $query=$_POST['data'];

    $results = $api->search($query, 'track'); 
    echo json.encode($results)
?>
```

I'm aware that the PHP method requires more lines of code and the use of vendor to access the Spotify PHP wrapper. From my examples you can see that the direct HTTPS method is more straightforward.

What I wish to know is if there is any security benefit of using PHP wrappers for API operations such as this example. Why are they used instead of straightforward AJAX requests?

For more complex requests I would always need to authenticate to Spotify and receive tokens when using a direct HTTP request. I'm trying to get my head around Client Side and Server Side code when it comes to authentication as I don't want my app to cause any security issues for users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important point in my eyes:
You have an API token in your PHP file. You do not want to provide this token through some JS files for the AJAX call right? Everyone could easily see your token by pressing F12.
Put simple: If the API call requires tokens or other access security NEVER use direct AJAX calls from client side.

Another point:
If you have an JS frontend you do not want to have a lot of logic there but if you basically have an app that does not utilize any other custom backend operations and is only calling the target API then you might not want to add your own backend for just a bit of listing and displaying.

An another point:
If you are using Javascript those files are cached client side. So yeah: If the API changes the cashed files might still be in use and your software will not work anymore.

And:
If some are worried about performance: Of course you are faster by directly calling an API from your client but the advantages and security you get from having your calls routed through your PHP files are worth a lot more.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for the recommendations on security, and efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you do with the returned information!

If you don't want to do anything else with the returned information, then you can purely display it to the end user. However, if you want to cache the results, or do some analyse on the request or requested results, such as user usage etc, then the backend PHP will facilitate that.

There is also the issue that with the direct API call, the network of the client will be used as opposed to the hosting server with the PHP call, in fetching the results. Along with this is the extra hop required in order to get the information from the PHP script (client calls PHP script, PHP scripts calls API, PHP script returns result to the client).

Comment: Yea, my entire website is built upon javascript so I think I'd rather do heavy processing within PHP. Think the PHP method is what I'll use. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

One of the benefits of using PHP is so you could add extra code or logic that you don't want to expose in your JS file. If you are interested in performance then obvs calling the Spotify endpoint directly from AJAX would improve it by a tiny bit.

Comment: why wouldnt you add logic in Javascript?

Comment: Logic that you don't want to expose in your JS code.
There are plenty of security reason you'd want to do that

Answer (score 1):

Javascript solution works only if you are using **Implicit grant flow** https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#implicit-grant-flow

Otherways you need server side solutions for authorisation. Because you will be working with secret keys.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of this. Thanks for the answer, it is very useful in context.